# Getting the singularities of a function defined by a series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

I am trying to locate the singularities that a linear transformation creates. I will not try to motivate this question, since it is already quite far from its starting point.

So, the question is the following.

Let $\Gamma(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}} - \frac{1}{z}$ and let 
$$f(z,\zeta)=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{m=0}^{n}f_{n,m} z^n \zeta^m$$
be a function holomorphic in both variables.

Let $L$ be a linear transformation that acts on $f$ by
$$L[f](z,\zeta) = \sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{m=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{2m} \frac{z^l}{l!} \Gamma^{(l)}(z)\frac{\binom{2m+n}{2m-l}}{\binom{2m+n}{2m}} \, f_{n,m} z^n \zeta^m. $$

Obviously, $L[f]$ is nsingular when $z = 2\pi i a$, $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ (minus the origin, but it may have branching singularities, so the origin can be singular in some sheets).

Is there any tool that can give me the location of the singularities of $L[f]$? Are there any obvious domains where $L[f]$ is not singular? Is there any other more convenient way to write $L[f]$?

EDIT: The sum can be also written as:
$$L[f](z,\zeta)=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n+2m)!} \, f_{n,m} \, z^n \, \zeta^m \, z^{-n} \, \frac{d^{2m}}{dz^{2m}} \, z^{n+2m}  \, \Gamma(z)$$

or alternatively as:

$$L[f](z,\zeta)=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{(n+m)!}{(n+3m)!} \, f_{n+m,m} \, z^{n+m} \, \zeta^m \, z^{-n-m} \, \frac{d^{2m}}{dz^{2m}} \, z^{n+3m}  \, \Gamma(z).$$